# Force network traffic to a particular router

Tags: networking, router, dlna

I have just had BT Infinity installed and it seems that the BT Home Hub has problems with my DLNA server (PS3 Media Server).  This seems to be a known issue judging by the number of posts I have found by others complaining about the same issue, so I am trying to work around it.

I have my BT hub connected to a homeplug, which the connects to a switch in another room.  The switch feeds my PS3 and a wireless access point.  Another homeplug on the network connects directly to a desktop PC in another room running Windows 7.  This computer is running the media server too.  The BT hub is the DHCP server for my network, my wireless access point doesn't have the ability to be a DHCP server.

Is there any way I can configure my Windows 7 desktop to communicate with my PS3 directly through the switch/wireless access point, rather than going through the BT hub (which seems to block the traffic)?

FYI, the reason I know that the BT hub is the culprit is because I can force PS3 Media server to use the WiFi connection on the desktop rather than the ethernet, which means its initial contact is to the wireless access point, which then routes to the PS3.  But if it uses the ethernet connection it must first go to the BT hub.

Would I have to get a new wireless access point that can also act as a DHCP server and turn off DHCP on the BT hub?